# Appium automation on simulator and physical device stopped working after updating to Xcode 11

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appium, xcode11

I was able to run automation scripts on simulators and physical devices (with varying success but at least they were working).

Now what seems to happen, on the iPhone 5 for example, it connects and the page appium.io opens, then nothing else happens.

The only error I can see in Appium is "Page 27752/0 not found. Already sent close_frame"

Nothing else has been updated except for Xcode, and I think before this I was on Xcode 9.2

This same script works fine with when automating Safari.

Version details below

MacOS 10.14.5
Appium 1.12.1
Xcode11
iPhone 5 OS 11.2.6

Apologies for any errors, I'm still new to this.

I actually don't know what to do to fix this. I've had so many problems getting automation to work with iOS that I'm reluctant to update anything at the moment. The automation works fine on Safari, just not iOS

I can't see where to attach the appium output log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue after updating to Xcode 11, seem like there is an issue with the Command Line Tools, you can roll it back to Xcode 10.2 like this:

[image: Command Line Tools]

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: When I try that it only gives me an option to use Xcode 11.0 There are no other versions in that Command Line Tools drop down menu

Comment: You can try to install another version of Xcode and use [Xcode Manager](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcode-install), this will install more than one version of the IDE and Command Line Tools, this should help you to get more options on the dropdown. Just a note the download and install process can take a while so be ready to wait.